How to make a backslash in a MacBook Pro Spanish keyboard with Latin American settings?
The backslash is the only symbol I cannot find on the keyboard. And I needed for several commands and applications. It is a MacBook Pro Spanish keyboard with Latin American settings?
Currently, I copy and paste, but I find it absurd to buy such an expensive machine and not be able to write a simple backslash.
I have Googled, but all the answers are unsatisfactory (and all are focused on the US layout).


According to this Reddit thread, the magic key combo should be:

Option+'

That ' key is the key between the 0 key and the ¿ key on the top row beneath the Fn keys.
Using Apple’s store website for “Magic Keyboard - Spanish (Latin American)” as a reference, the key is highlighted with a red circle:

